# Error occur during Installation of LightGBM

Tags: git, cmake

I am using R studio, Now i want to install LightGBM for window. I have Installed Git for Window, CMAKE and MINGW64. The path of GIT is

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin

and the path of CMAKE is

> C:\Users\MuhammadMaqsood\Downloads\cmake-3.13.3-win64-x64\bin

I have set  C:\Users\MuhammadMaqsood\Downloads\cmake-3.13.3-win64-x64\bin as path for both  user variable and system variable as shown in image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m82Cd.png)

I have run the following command for the installation of LightGbm

> git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM
>
> cd LightGBM
>
> mkdir build
>
> cd build
>
> cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DUSE_OPENMP=OFF ..
>
> mingw32-make.exe -j4

Now i have to face some two types of error.

> 1. When i set C:\Program Files\Git\bin as path for user variable and system variable then i show this error that **cmake command not found**.

> 2.when i set
>   C:\Users\MuhammadMaqsood\Downloads\cmake-3.13.3-win64-x64\bin as path
>   for user variable and system variable then i show this error that
>   **sh.exe found in your path. as shown in figure** [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwyuj.png)

I am trying this about one month if any one has any information about this then answer me.

Comment: The figure suggests to remove from the *PATH* a directory, which contains `sh.exe`. In your case, it is  `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` directory. Why do you add this directory to the *PATH*, as CMake complains about it?

Comment: Now i have remove  C:\Program Files\Git\bin from path. My recent path is C:\Users\MuhammadMaqsood\Downloads\cmake-3.13.3-win64-x64\bin . Now it shows message that sh.exe found in your path.

Comment: Which directory contains `sh.exe` after that? (The directory is printed in the error message). Have you tried to remove from the *PATH* that directory too?

Comment: yes i have remove the sh.exe from this directory C:\Program Files\Git\user\bin . after  removing shows the same message sh.exe found in your path.

Comment: Looks like a directory `C:\Program Files\Git\user\bin` is still in your PATH...

Comment: Tsyvarev . i have been deleted sh.exe from C:\Program Files\Git\user\bin. But the same error occur.

Comment: Hm, try to clean build directory and configure the project again.